# Hacking the Muse (Why interrogate the transhuman if Muse knows it all?)

Tags: eclipse-phase

The Muse is a AI companion that assists its owner on every day basis. Often it does so from early childhood and knows it's master very well. It resides in master's mesh inserts and to be able to serve master well it has to store a wealth of information there.

So: why retort to transhuman's psychosurgery, torture or VR fork interrogation if theirs Muse has full access to their senses and registers it as part of its duty? Isn't it easier to hack the Muse than to crack transhuman mind?

But is Muse's knowledge of its master and their proceedings really complete? I expect that Muse can be asked to skip recording some sensory input, even delete already recorded one from its own database... But what if it owes higher allegiance to authorities (like Titanian Muses could) or has already been hacked and some kind of wiretapping has been placed? Or does it simply log deletion request for purposes of maintaining database integrity?

How much can be learned from interrogating or wiretapping Muse and how is it done?

Comment: How much can you learn about a person's digital footprint now a days? How trustworthy is it? Can you think of ways to use misinformation on would be captors?...

Answer (score 6):

You've already answered part of your own question: Muses provide only an incomplete and possibly untrustworthy parallel of the character's mind and memories.

Think of a Muse as an actual, permanent, but otherwise "imaginary friend." This made a good rule of thumb for the game I ran, and the particulars of deletion logs, database integrity, and other Muse hacking all just got used as techno-babble for whatever made the story go.

For example, all characters had reliable Muses, except for one PC. He'd had a Muse of a fork of his ex-wife, whom he still loved. He lost that Muse after being captured and tortured early in the game, and its replacement was an illegal alpha fork of his torturer. The replacement Muse was very untrustworthy! It functioned as an on-board spy. This worked better than psychosurgical modification of the PC for two reasons. First, it provided the torturer a backup mind, and it kept the PC's other allies from having reason to distrust him.

Comment: I do like your example!